# How to tap to system active app button on Appium (Android)

Tags: java, android, appium

I need to open all active application`s menu on emulator. I was find code how to tap on system button in particular Home and Back, but i cant find third button keyCode.

```
((AndroidDriver)this.getMobileDriver()).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));
```

[image: System buttons]

How to tap for box button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `AndroidKey.HOME` with `AndroidKey.APP_SWITCH` in your code.
Here the full list of all available key constants: https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/nativekey/AndroidKey.html